# Digital logic, K Map- Essential Prime Implicants

Tags: logic, optimization

[image]

I have solved  the above problem in two ways.And both the times I have a unique solution with the same number of gates.

According to my understanding of Essential Prime Implicants, This particular case does not contain any essential prime implicants, as two ways of solution is possible.Is my interpretation correct?

But is it possible to have a solution without EPI's?
Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we have some context? I have no idea what you are talking about. If it's just me and caused by the fact that I'm unaware of the associated field, then it's probably fine. But if your question actually lacks needed information, this needs to be addressed.

Comment: The context is to list all the essential prime implicants. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicant

Comment: @Stefan: It's because this terminology is well-known in computer science but not in mathematics.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks for clearing that up. I have a minor in theoretical computer science, but didn't recognize any of that notation.

Comment: @Stefan: Yea it is common in some CS courses but I won't be surprised if it was omitted entirely from others, since the only use for it is in designing logic circuits to partly minimize the number of logical operations (actually it's not very good at that!) and never ever used anywhere else!

Comment: @user21820 That sounds *way* too applicable that it could have possibly come up in the courses I was interested in (;

Comment: @Stefan: Haha it sounds useful, but it's actually quite dreadful. At the end of the day when you're building the circuit, you don't just want prime implicants, but you want to reuse computed terms. That is very weakly correlated with the number of prime implicants. And usually, ingenuity is far better than minimizing prime implicants; for example see https://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/logic/lookahead-carry.xhtml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct that this is an example where there are no essential prime implicants. But your first diagram is slightly incorrect, because your $Q'S'$ implicant should be 'circled' to indicate that it is joined at the top and bottom.

Another example with no essential prime implicants is $P'Q'R' + P'QS + PQR + PQ'S'$, which is equivalent to $P'R'S + QRS + PRS' + Q'R'S'$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And Q'S'  is covered using the four corners, hence it is grouped in that fashion. Is there a way I could circle them.

Comment: @turtle: Yes, let me see if I can depict using LaTeX: $\lrcorner\ \llcorner\\\urcorner\ \ulcorner$ but with rounded corners.

Comment: Oh okay. Grouping is correct. The style used to group them  is wrong. I will correct it. Thanks :)

Comment: @turtle: You're welcome! Off-topic, why don't you use "" in your username? =)

Comment: @turtle: I meant that you can actually use the unicode symbol in your username on StackExchange. =D

Comment: Off topic, I would like to use for  sure :))  and yeah got that a little late ;) but not possible, cause username is minimum three characters!

Comment: @turtle: Haha anyway I was just amusingly wondering how funny it would be to ping a user with a "" in the username. Oh and if you're happy with my answer you can accept it. =)

Comment: Accepted the answer. Off topic, Actually unicodes are not allowed as usernames. I had tried using one long back and failed. And I think its still not acceptable and kinda of understandable. Unless its programmed computer cant tell if its a ASCII code or unicode by itself might be the reason. I guess!!